# Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type '(number | null)[]'

Tags: typescript

I have TS complaining about this code:

```
const data = values?.map((item: PointDTO) => item.y);

const chartData: ChartData = {
  labels,
  datasets: [{ data }],
};
```

The error message is :

```
Type '(number | undefined)[] | undefined' is not assignable to type '(number | ScatterDataPoint | BubbleDataPoint | null)[]'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type '(number | null)[]'
```

So I changed my code to:

```
const data = values?.map((item: PointDTO) => item.y) ?? null;
```

But this didn't solve my issue.

How can I solve this please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the following line is the one that is displaying the error:
`datasets: [{ data }],` you will need to change the first line of your example to the following:

`const data = values?.map((item: PointDTO) => item.y).filter((y) => y !== undefined) ?? [];`

Explanation to changes:

- If the `values` variable was set to null - `data` would have originally been assigned with `undefined` by the optional operator. This is fixed by adding `?? []` at the end which will default the result to an empty array instead.
- If any of the `item.y` properties were `undefined`, `data` would have originally been assigned with an array that contains undefined values as follows `[undefined, undefined, 1234, undefined]`. This is fixed by `.filter((y) => y !== undefined)` which removes any of the undefined entries from the array and would change the previous result to this `[1234]`.

Comment: Consider using `?? []`. `||` does work, but there is differences between `null`, `undefined` and null-ish values that does not apply here but does when looking at `number`, `string`, `enum`, etc.

Comment: The only reason why ```??``` would be better here is if the ```values``` variable was as a number, string or a boolean type - which I would doubt as OP is using it as an array. Hence, due to the fact that in the context of this question the result will be the same for either ```||``` or ```??```, I will hold my original response and allow the OP/viewers to make the choice themselves.

Comment: The why for me is that one works the way I expect all of the time and it is purpose built for that scenario. It might be newer, but so is your `?.` usage.

Comment: I will have to agree that for best coding practices ```??``` should be chosen over ```||``` and because OP does appear to be usingTypeScript version 3.7+ (assumed from the syntax of the examples), I will edit the answer to fit this.

Answer (score 0):

[`values?.****`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) will return undefined if values is `values` is [nullish](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Nullish) (`undefined` or `null`). This is the reason for you getting `undefined` as possible value.

But your data is expected to be of type `(number | ScatterDataPoint | BubbleDataPoint | null)[]`. So you have to return an array:

```
const data = values?.map((item: PointDTO) => item.y) ?? []
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but this didn't work, I'm getting a new error:
 `Type '(number | undefined)[]' is not assignable to type '(number | ScatterDataPoint | BubbleDataPoint | null)[]'.
  Type 'number | undefined' is not assignable to type 'number | ScatterDataPoint | BubbleDataPoint | null'.
    Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'number | ScatterDataPoint | BubbleDataPoint | null'`

Comment: The issue is that `undefined` is not assignable to `null`. I'm not sure what the best practice to deal with that is when some libraries prefer to user `T | undefined` (as opposed to `T | null`) to represent optional types. It's incredibly frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

You might have to specify that the variable is undefinable:

```
    let dataPoint: DataPoint | undefined;
```